# How to select which concrete instance method should be called inside a generic class in Java

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have a generic class that does not know its concrete type:

```
public class TheGeneric<T> {
    public TheGeneric(T t) {
        int return = t.callConcreteMethod();
        // Do something ...
    }
}
```

Now I want to put the following class as parameter to the generic class:

```
class TheConcrete {

    int a, b;

    public TheConcrete(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;

        // Do something with 'a' and do something else with 'b'
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

Property *a* is not the same as property *b*.

Now I want to have a choice which of these both instance methods to use in place of `callConcreteMethod()`.

As I understand, an interface with a method `get()`, which the concrete class could implement, would not be enough. The interface would have to implement a variable amount of these methods.

In Java 8, I though the solution could be to use the new functional interfaces *Supplier* or *Consumer* to let the generic class know which concrete instance method it has to choose/call. So a instantiation call could look like this:

```
TheConcrete concrete = new Concrete(1, 2);
TheGeneric<TheConcrete> generic = new TheGeneric<>(concrete, TheConcrete::getB);
```

If this is really possible, I don't know how to finish this approach to get the return type of the concrete method.

Do exist other approaches and/or design pattern to implement this idea?

The important constraint is that different instance methods are part of the same class and each of them should be selectable to call through only one step (call) in a generic class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close to the solution but neither `Supplier` nor `Consumer` are appropriate here. You need a functional interface which consumes the instance and returns the property value. Since the type of your property is `int`, `ToIntFunction<T>` or `Function<T,Integer>` are appropriate.

The code for `TheGeneric` may look like:

```
public class TheGeneric<T> {
    public TheGeneric(T t, ToIntFunction<T> method) {
        int value=method.applyAsInt(t);
        // Do something ...
    }
}
```

and the use case derived from your sketch:

```
TheConcrete concrete = new TheConcrete(1, 2);
TheGeneric<TheConcrete> generic = new TheGeneric<>(concrete, TheConcrete::getB);
```

---

It isn’t hard to derive a pre- Java 8 solution from this. Just rewrite the method reference to nested classes and, preferably store an instance for each property in a `static` field for efficiency:

```
class TheConcrete {
    static final ToIntFunction<TheConcrete> GET_A=new ToIntFunction<TheConcrete>() {
        public int applyAsInt(TheConcrete instance) {
            return instance.getA();
        }
    };
    static final ToIntFunction<TheConcrete> GET_B=new ToIntFunction<TheConcrete>() {
        public int applyAsInt(TheConcrete instance) {
            return instance.getB();
        }
    };
 … rest as in your original class
```

Then you might use it like:

```
TheConcrete concrete = new TheConcrete(1, 2);
TheGeneric<TheConcrete> generic = new TheGeneric<>(concrete, TheConcrete.GET_B);
```

which doesn’t differ too much from the Java 8 usage.

Note that this also allows a smooth transition. You may replace the `static` fields without the need to change the rest of the application like this:

```
static final ToIntFunction<TheConcrete> GET_A=TheConcrete::getA;
static final ToIntFunction<TheConcrete> GET_B=TheConcrete::getB;
```

---

Note that `ToIntFunction<T>` is a Java 8 interface but the entire thing works without problems if you create your own `interface` named `ToIntFunction<T>` having the single method `int applyAsInt(T value)`.

---

If you want to support arbitrary typed properties, the generic class needs another type parameter:

```
public class TheGeneric<T,V> {
    public TheGeneric(T t, Function<T,V> method) {
        V value=method.apply(t);
        // Do something ...
    }
}
```

I think the adaptation of the rest is straight-forward then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the strategy pattern. Instead of parameter TheConcrete::getB you can pass Strategy Object, that will call getB or getWhicheverMethod of TheConcrete class and then will return value or do some other job.

This Strategy Object can be retrieved by static factory method of TheConcrete, which can be part of the common interface, but this depends on your needs.

Check Wiki, it describes it well http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern